# React: Setting this.props in constructor...? (not trying to mutate props)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

**I am not trying to mutate props.**
I just want to have access to this.props in methods called in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.props = props; // CAN I? There is no errors or warnings

    const filtered = this.filterValue(props.value);
    this.state = {
        value: filtered,
    }
}

filterValue(value){
    // here I need this.props.*
}
```

I know there is few ways to do it e.g. additional argument passed to filterValue, however I want it to be as simple as possible. I think that above code is 
quite intuitive, the question is: can I do it like this? React will override this.props anyway.

Comment: You can do this, but `super` probably already did that anyway.

Comment: omg, you're right. I'm not sure why I didn't notice that. I was certain that props are undefined in the constructor. I probably forgot to pass props to super ;/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access props using `this.props` in methods as described in [the `React.Component` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#instance-properties):

> Instance Properties:
>
> - props
> - state

If you are curious, you can look at the source code of the [`ReactComponent` constructor](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/faa4218632ca21f3af731fb6c14849fc054fca15/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L18).

Comment: Is this still true? May you please update the link to the source where they do this?

Comment: @Noitidart yes, this is still true. I updated the answer above.

Comment: Thanks @Alik! In the edit its not clear. So it is safe to mutate the this.props or event set this.props to a new object?